# What happens if you don't attend to a critically low stat?

Tags: stack-egg

If you were to just ignore users, or quality, for example, will it cause problems beyond not having the hearts?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you ignore a critical stat for too long, you get shut down. If you have a flag, you can use it to save yourself. From my tests on an abandoned Stack Exchange site:

- You can *always* ignore a critical stat three times.
- You can ignore a critical stat four times, unless something else would cause it to decay faster.

  - A downvote causes Users decay.
  - Low Questions causes Answers decay.
  - High Traffic causes Quality decay.
- You can *never* ignore a critical stat five times in a row.

If you simply want to be safe, ignore three times. If you are attempting a perfect game, look for situations where you can ignore four times.

Comment: lol.  I like your edit comment.

Comment: I've noticed that *not playing* reverts the low stats.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Reverts them to.... what?

Comment: To full. They will be full when you check.

Comment: Can anyone aside from Ismael confirm that not playing allows you to ignore a critical stat indefinitely? I didn't get a chance to test this myself, and now the game is gone.

Answer (score 4):

It will force you to use a flag, or terminate the game, you cannot ignore them to long. I think the limit is four days, although I don't have tests to back it up.